# What thread-safe collection is appropriate for this scenario?

Tags: .net, collections, thread-safety

I have a singleton class handling Subscribe and Unsubscribe requests from different clients running in different threads. The singleton contains a collection of Subscribers.  Before adding or removing, the class needs to validate that the element hasn't already been added or deleted.

Normally I would implement this using a List or a HashSet calling Contains before each operation, but if I want to use one of the new classes in the System.Collections.Concurrent namespace, the only option I see is to use a ConcurrentDictionary with a dummy value.

Is this my best option or is there something I'm overlooking? By the way, performance is not really a factor to consider.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should stick with [`ConcurrentDictionary`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd287191.aspx) ...

Comment: "and unlike sets, bags support duplicates." vs.  "Before adding or removing, the class needs to validate that the element hasn't already been added or deleted."

Answer (score 0):

Why dont you use ConcurrentDictionary backed with Blocking Queue. BlockingQueue seems to fit your producer/consumer scheme, and ConcurrentDictionary for your lookups.

Comment: I'm not sure my scenario fits a producer/consumer scheme. Unsubscribe requests don't need to follow the same order as the Subscribe requests so I'm failing to see what the benefit would be of using a queue in this case. I don't see the added benefit compared to just using a dictionary.