# How do I unfold an AggregateException into individual exceptions?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, exception, thread-safety

It seems like I am getting threading errors as a result of an inconsistent state of my `IEnumerable`.  Specifically, `List<T>`.

Here's my workflow:

```
List<string> IDs = getIDs();
RunTask(IDs);
RunTask(IDs);

public void RunTask(List<string> IDs)
{
    TaskScheduler scheduler = new TaskScheduler();
    TaskFactory factory = new TaskFactory(scheduler);
    var tasks = IDs.Select(name => factory.StartNew(() => action(name))).ToArray();
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
```

I am getting a generic error on my `WaitAll()` call.

My thinking is that I am getting some sort of unsynchronized IEnumerator, and that I need to make a copy of my `List` via `Array.CopyTo()`, then pass it into my multiple threads.

This is my exception:

```
Error: One or more errors occurred.
One or more errors occurred.
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks, Int32 millisecondsTimeout)
at System.Threading.Tasks.Task.WaitAll(Task[] tasks)
```

Any thoughts on this matter?

Comment: Have you considered using something like a Mutex to block multiple threads from accessing the list simultaneously?

Comment: You don't, it's not safe. See the answers to this question for some good information. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601611/no-concurrentlistt-in-net-4-0 Edit - I didn't notice you weren't writing to the list. Multiple readers is fine.

Comment: Unfortunately, I need both threads to access the data in the list.

Comment: You can read from a list perfectly safely from multiple threads.  You're not mutating the list here so it's fine.  The problem is in code not posted (like whatever `action` is).

Comment: @tkeE2036 it seems like people are just downvoting questions they don't like, regardless of quality

Comment: Oh, and technically you're not even accessing the `List` from multiple threads.  The two `RunTask` methods aren't run in parallel because of the `WaitAll`.  The tasks that are run in parallel don't access the list directly, just strings that the list references (which is fine, and couldn't ever break anything since `string`s are immutable.

Comment: @climbage yes, downvotes happen far more often than they should... seems like most don't even read the question and assume that I'm too lazy to test it myself :/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I don't think this is a threading error - it should be safe as long as each task does not modify the `IDs` list. `Task.WaitAll()` throws an `AggregateException` if any of the waited tasks throw an exception or are cancelled.

You can access the `InnerExceptions` on the exception to see what the error(s) are.

```
try
{
    Task.WaitAll(tasks);
}
catch(AggregateException ex)
{
    foreach(Exception in ex.InnerExceptions) { ... }
}
```

Comment: I ended up doing something very similar to this and it fixed my problem by giving me the entire stack trace - turned out my service did not have the correct file permissions.  Marking yours as correct, thanks!