# wcf singleton service multithreaded

Tags: c#, multithreading, wcf

I have a self hosted wcf singleton service. There are two client consuming it. Service has one instance variable of type List. There are three methods. One to add, one to remove and last to check if list is empty. Client1 is using only add method. Client2 uses remove and isEmpty method. I am wondering is lock required in this case in these methods? Any better approach for this problem to enhance performance?

```
[ServiceBehavior(InstanceContextMode = InstanceContextMode.Single,ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple)]
public class Service : IService
{
    // will it be better to make it static ?
    List<Parameter> _fileList = new List<Parameter>();

    // Is this required ?
    readonly object _lock = new object();

    public bool FileEnQueue(Parameter parameter)
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            _fileList.Add(parameter);
        }
        return true;
    }

    public Parameter FileDeQueue()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            Parameter parameter = new Parameter();
            if (_fileList.Count > 0)
            {
                parameter = _fileList.ElementAt(0);
                _fileList.Remove(parameter);
            }
            return parameter;
        }
    }

    public bool IsQueueEmpty()
    {
        lock (_lock)
        {
            if (_fileList.Count == 0)
                return true;
            else
                return false;
        }
    }  
}
```

Comment: when you say enhance performance could you state what you mean by that ? what is slow and how are you measuring it ?

Comment: @marc_s  ConcurrencyMode = ConcurrencyMode.Multiple doesn't it allow multiple thread at same time ?

Comment: @MauricioGracia if lock in not required and i am using it , it will make this slow (no of request processed per sec). isn't it? so some technique which will allow it to handle more request .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well if one client adds while another removes and if you dont handle concurrency you could have trouble or inconsistent state.

So yes I would suggest a Lock or syncronization mechanism on the shared info/list

Comment: the way i am doing it..is it correct ? or is there any better way of doing it?

Comment: @dream_machine see for example http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16952182/c-sharp-list-concurrency

Comment: @dream_machine also some important notes are mentioned here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1813557/listt-concurrent-removing-and-adding

Comment: @dream_machine also this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997305%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing it right? Yes, but this type of code is very hard to test. It's also hard to debug if you do make a mistake.

The better solution is to use a class that does it for you: [ConcurrentQueue](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267265(v=vs.110).aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Are you doing this right? NO!

What are you doing wrong? Reinventing the wheel.

It looks like you are trying to reinvent the `MessageQueue` pattern. The obvious solution, is to use a Message Queue software package.

PLEASE LOOK AT ONE OF THE FOLLOWING

- MSMQ
- RabbitMQ
- Websphere
- RavenMQ