# Wait for next element in shared List in a C# concurrent producer / consumer pattern

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading

I have a

```
List<object> listOfData;
```

in C# that gets data every X minute from a `getDataBackgroundWorker`.

I have another `processDataBackgroundWorker` that waits for the data from `listOfData` and processes it.

How can I make sure that I only get unique data from `listOfData` ( new data is added always ) and how can I ask the `processDataBackgroundWorker` to pause when there is no new data in `listOfData`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`List<>` [isn't a great choice in concurrency](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6601832/314291) - there are out of the box alternatives, like `ConcurrentBag, ConcurrentQueue` which already have a lot of hard work done for you.

Here's an implementation of a producer-consumer pattern, using a `BlockingCollection` implementation as per [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997371(v=vs.110).aspx),

- The `BlockingCollection` is backed with a `ConcurrentQueue`, assuming that we are serially pull data in sequence on the consumer.
- Methods which iterate over `BlockingCollection` block (with little overhead) until an item is available (i.e. your 'pause' is inherent - no need for a looped check with `Thread.Sleep`s on the consumer).
- Termination is inherently built in, when the producer calls `CompletedAdding`
- If you have more than one concurrent (competing) consumer, only one consumer will get an item, i.e. the duplication condition shouldn't be a concern (unless you mean the producer actually adds duplicates in the first place).

```
var queue = new BlockingCollection<string>(new ConcurrentQueue<string>());
var producer = Task.Run(() =>
{
    // Produce some random messages, with delays in between
    queue.Add("Hello!");
    Thread.Sleep(1000);
    queue.Add("World!");
    Thread.Sleep(2000);
    Enumerable.Range(0, 100)
        .ToList()
        .ForEach(x => queue.Add(x.ToString()));
    queue.CompleteAdding();
});

var consumer = Task.Run(() =>
    {
        while (!queue.IsCompleted)
        {
            try
            {
                Debug.WriteLine(queue.Take());
            }
            catch (InvalidOperationException)
            {
            }
        }
    });
Task.WaitAll(producer, consumer);
```

Comment: Thanks for the solution, I used ConcurrentBag and it worked for me. The above is another option.