# Using the ConcurrentBag type as a thread-safe substitute for a List

Tags: c#, collections

In genereal, would using the `ConcurrentBag` type be an acceptable thread-safe substitute for a `List`? I have read some answers on here that have suggested the use of `ConcurrentBag` when one was having a problem with thread safety with generic Lists in C#.

After reading a bit about `ConcurrentBag`, however, it seems performing a lot of searches and looping through the collection does not match with its intended usage. It seems to mostly be intended to solve producer/consumer problems, where jobs are being (some-what randomly) added and removed from the collection.

This is an example of the type of (`IEnumerable`) operations I want to use with the `ConcurrentBag`:

```
...
private readonly ConcurrentBag<Person> people = new ConcurrentBag<Person>();

public void AddPerson(Person person)
{
   people.Add(person);
}

public Person GetPersonWithName(string name)
{
   return people.Where(x => name.Equals(x.Name)).FirstOrDefault();
}
...
```

Would this cause performance concerns, and is it even a correct way to use a `ConcurrentBag` collection?

Comment: @terrybozzio In this case, 4. I think I came across the fact that there is a performance issue in 4 that was fixed in 4.5 when instantiating ConcurrentBags. In this case, only one ConcurrentBag is instantiated as a singleton. I am mostly concerned about the theory of using ConcurrentBag as a replacement for a List, though.

Comment: If order matters at all, `ConcurrentBag<T>` is not a good substitute for `List<T>`. Threads will remove items in a different order depending on which thread added the item. See http://www.informit.com/guides/content.aspx?g=dotnet&seqNum=842 for more information about that.

Comment: @JimMischel Thanks for the useful link. Your blog also confirms my suspicion that ConcurrentBag seems to be intended for a pure producer/consumer application. This seems to indicate it is not really intended for operations where you are Searching/Deleting specific items in a collection, in other words, List operations that would normally be of time N. In these instances, order does not matter, however, the ability to search/delete specific items is used.

Comment: take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601611/no-concurrentlistt-in-net-4-0

Comment: and in particular if your after IEnumberable + Add why not ConcurrentQueue?

Answer (score 4):

.NET's in-built concurrent data structures are most designed for patterns like producer-consumer, where there is a constant flow of work through the container.

In your case, the list seems to be long-term (relative to the lifetime of the class) storage, rather than just a resting place for some data before a consumer comes along to take it away and do something with it. In this case I'd suggest using a normal `List<T>` (or whichever non-concurrent collection is most appropriate for the operations you're intending), and simply using `lock`s to control access to it.

Comment: The question mentions a lot of searches, for which a List may not be optimal.

Comment: @WarrenDew Thanks, I've added a note to that effect

Answer (score 1):

A Bag is just the most general form of collection, allowing multiple identical entries, and without even the ordering of a List.  It does happen to be useful in producer/consumer contexts where fairness is not an issue, but it is not specifically designed for that.

Because a Bag does not have any structure with respect to its contents, it's not very suitable for performing searches.  In particular, the use case you mention will require time that scales with the size of the bag.  A HashSet might be better if you don't need to be able to store multiple copies of an item and if manual synchronization is acceptable for your use case.

Comment: `HashSet` is not thread safe. It is better to use `ConcurrentDictionary` for thread safety.

Comment: @Norfolc That's why I mentioned manual synchronization.  ConcurrentDictionary may also be an option.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I understand the ConcurrentBag it makes use of multiple lists. It creates a List for each thread using the ConcurrentBag. Thus when reading or accessing the ConcurrentBag within the same thread again the performance should be roughly the same as when just using a normal List, but if the ConcurrentBag is accessed from a different thread there will be a performance overhead as it has to search for the value in the "internal" lists created for each thread.

The MSDN page says the following regarding the ConcurrentBag.

> Bags are useful for storing objects when ordering doesn't matter, and unlike sets, bags support duplicates. ConcurrentBag is a thread-safe bag implementation, optimized for scenarios where the same thread will be both producing and consuming data stored in the bag.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd381779%28v=VS.100%29.aspx

Answer (score 0):

> In genereal, would using the ConcurrentBag type be an acceptable thread-safe substitute for a List?

No, not in general, because, concurring with Warren Dew, a List is ordered, while a Bag is not (surely mine isn't ;)

But in cases where (potentially concurrent) reads greatly outnumber writes, you could just [copy-on-write wrap your List](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30769838/709537).

That is a general solution, as you are working with original List instances, except (as explained in more detail in above link) you have to make sure that everyone modifying the List uses the appropriate copy-on-write utility method - which you could enforce by using [`List.AsReadOnly()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e78dcd75.aspx).

In highly concurrent programs, copy-on-write has many desirable performance properties in mostly-read scenarios, compared to locking.