# How to avoid explicit lock in asynchronous programming in C#?

Tags: c#, asynchronous, collections, thread-safety, locking

I was working on a project written in **C#** where I had couple of collections that would be accessed and modified by different threads/tasks, therefore I used the ***lock*** keyword(quite a lot). I followed the notes mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/251391/why-is-lockthis-bad) and other references/tutorials available online to utilize this keyword properly. At the exam, I was asked how I could avoid these explicit locks. Thanks in advance and I hope this question is proper to be asked here.

Here is some code sample(there are other loops and method calls as well, I deleted them to have a shorter sample) :

```
            try
        {
            lock (this)
            {
                if (!IsReplaying)
                {
                                        //removing igonored tracks from bufferlist 
                    for (int i = 0; i < BufferList.Count; i++)
                    {
                        for (int j = 0; j < ListOfIgnoredTracks.Count; j++)
                        {
                            CAT62Data dataitem = BufferList[i];
                            if (BufferList[i].CAT62DataItems[10].value != null)
                            {
                                if (BufferList[i].CAT62DataItems[10] != null && BufferList[i].CAT62DataItems[10].value != null)
                                {
                                    if (dataitem.CAT62DataItems[10].value.ToString() == ListOfIgnoredTracks[j].CAT62DataItems[10].value.ToString() && !dataitem.IsModified && !dataitem.IsUserAdded)
                                    {
                                        BufferList.RemoveAt(i--);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    BufferList.Clear();

                    RemoveLostTracks(new DateTime());
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: Too broad. This covers a good part of a decent book and is way more than a Q&A format can handle.

Comment: @TomTom Couild you please refer to a source that I can read up more about this?

Comment: @dotctor I uploaded some code :)

Answer (score 1):

One of the answers, you can use instead of your standard collections this namespace.

```
System.Collections.Concurrent
```

Here you will find the same collections, which are **Thread Safe**.
so you don't need to write **lock** anymore.

Comment: I actually looked at it but based on this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601611/no-concurrentlistt-in-net-4-0) it is not acting asynchronously.

Comment: @arvind. These collections are used when many threads try to add elements or remove elemets from that collections.So that threads don't 
prevent each other,they use this collections