# Updating List in ConcurrentDictionary

Tags: c#, concurrency

So I have a IList as the value in my ConcurrentDictionary.

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, IList<string>> list1 = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, IList<string>>;
```

In order to update a value in a list I do this:

```
if (list1.ContainsKey[key])
{
  IList<string> templist;
  list1.TryGetValue(key, out templist);
  templist.Add("helloworld");
}
```

However, does adding a string to *templist* update the ConcurrentDictionary? If so, is the update thread-safe so that no data corruption would occur?

Or is there a better way to update or create a list inside the ConcurrentDictionary

**EDIT**

If I were to use a ConcurrentBag instead of a List, how would I implement this? More specifically, how could I update it? ConcurrentDictionary's TryUpdate method feels a bit excessive.

Does ConcurrentBag.Add update the ConcurrentDictionary in a thread-safe mannar?

```
ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentBag<string>> list1 = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentBag<string>>
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Firstly, there's no need to do `ContainsKey()` *and* `TryGetValue()`.

You should just do this:

```
IList<string> templist;

if (list1.TryGetValue(key, out templist))
    templist.Add("helloworld");
```

In fact your code as written has a race condition.

Inbetween one thread calling `ContainsKey()` and `TryGetValue()` a different thread may have removed the item with that key. Then `TryGetValue()` will return `tempList` as null, and then you'll get a null reference exception when you call `tempList.Add()`.

Secondly, yes: There's another possible threading issue here. You don't know that the `IList<string>` stored inside the dictionary is threadsafe.

Therefore calling `tempList.Add()` is not guaranteed to be safe.

You could use `ConcurrentQueue<string>` instead of `IList<string>`. This is probably going to be the most robust solution.

Note that simply locking access to the `IList<string>` wouldn't be sufficient.

This is no good:

```
if (list1.TryGetValue(key, out templist))
{
    lock (locker)
    {
        templist.Add("helloworld");
    }
}
```

unless you also use the same lock everywhere else that the `IList` may be accessed. This is not easy to achieve, hence it's better to either use a `ConcurrentQueue<>` or add locking to this class and change the architecture so that no other threads have access to the underlying IList.

Answer (score 5):

Operations on a thread-safe dictionary are thread-safe by key, so to say. So as long as you access your values (in this case an `IList<T>`) only from one thread, you're good to go.

The ConcurrentDictionary does **not** prevent two threads at the same time to access the value beloning to one key.

Comment: I didn't think for one moment that it was you. I know that you always explain downvotes! :)

Answer (score 5):

You can use ConcurrentDictionary.AddOrUpdate method to add item to list in thread-safe way. Its simpler and should work fine.

```
var list1 = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, IList<string>>();
list1.AddOrUpdate(key, 
      new List<string>() { "test" }, (k, l) => { l.Add("test"); return l;});
```

**UPD**

According to [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [sources](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,1206), factories, which was passed to `AddOrUpdate` method will be run out of lock scope, so calling `List` methods inside factory delegate is NOT thread safe.

See comments under this answer.

Comment: Alright, thanks for that. Now to comment on your actual implementation: that will still cause threading issues. What if another thread is iterating over the list at the moment `AddOrUpdate()` is called?

Comment: @CodeCaster Obviously, if we are using non thread safe data structure in multithread env, this is not safe. Bu I thought that question is about adding value to list in multithreaded way. If OP want to get access to list in multithreaded way, he should use multithreaded data structure.

Comment: The changes to the list are still not safe when doing this.  This code can still end up mutating the list from multiple threads at the same time, with all sorts of problematic results possible.

Comment: @tym32167 If you know that accessing the list isn't safe, then *don't say that this is safe*.  Clearly this is being used in a multithreaded context, given that the whole point of the question is asking if this is safe in a multithreaded context.

Comment: @Servy my piece of code is safe in multithreaded context. It is not safe to use my code and try to modify same list in other thread. Why should I explain to someone that using non-safe List<T> in multithreaded env is not safe? This is obvious.

Comment: @tym32167 No, your code is not safe.  Your code is potentially accessing a list from multiple threads, and can break.

Comment: In documentation it is stated that "`updateValueFactory` delegate is called outside the locks to avoid the problems that can arise from executing unknown code under a lock." so updating like this is not thread safe.

Comment: see remarks section https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.concurrent.concurrentdictionary-2.addorupdate?view=netframework-4.7.2

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary thanks for reminding me this, yep, now I realizing what was problem (it easier just to look at [this](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/Collections/Concurrent/ConcurrentDictionary.cs,1206)). My answer is not thread safe, I will remove it later or will keep it just for history.

Comment: I think its good to keep it or maybe update it to indicate this is wrong and put correct usage if you want. I think its a common mistake (I made that mistake too)

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary correct usage already present in another answer, but I updated mine with reference to comments, thx.

Comment: These comments are highly recommended to read. I made this mistake too.

Answer (score 2):

The `ConcurrentDictionary` has no effect on whether you can apply changes to value objects in a thread-safe manner or not. That is the reponsiblity of the value object (the `IList`-implementation in your case).

Looking at the answers of [No ConcurrentList<T> in .Net 4.0?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6601611/no-concurrentlistt-in-net-4-0) there are some good reasons why there is no `ConcurrentList` implementation in .net.

Basically you have to take care of thread-safe changes yourself. The most simple way is to use the lock operator. E.g.

```
lock (templist)
{
   templist.Add("hello world");
}
```

Another way is to use the [`ConcurrentBag`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/dd381779(v=vs.110).aspx) in the .net Framework. But this way is only useful for you, if you do not rely on the `IList` interface and the ordering of items.

Comment: I updated the question. Does updating the Bag update the Dictionary?

Answer (score 2):

it has been already mentioned about what would be the best solution ConcurrentDictionary with ConcurrentBag. Just going to add how to do that

```
 ConcurrentBag<string> bag= new ConcurrentBag<string>();
 bag.Add("inputstring"); 
 list1.AddOrUpdate(key,bag,(k,v)=>{
     v.Add("inputString");
     return v;
 });
```

Comment: I think you can replace `bag` with an inline `new ConcurrentBag<string> {"inputstring"}`

Answer (score 0):

> does adding a string to templist update the ConcurrentDictionary?

It does not.

Your thread safe collection (Dictionary) holds references to non-thread-safe collections (IList). So changing those is not thread safe.

I suppose you should consider using mutexes.

Comment: You're answering a different question than you quoted.  Contrary to your answer, the update to the temp list *is* observable from other contexts getting the list from the dictionary, and that's precisely why it's not safe to do so.

Comment: "Is observable" does not mean it is updated. The dictionary is not changed as an object in any way. It holds (!) references to non thread safe collections, so of course any changes are observable. But that is also the reason why it is not safe.

Comment: And based on their later clarification, they clearly were asking if the change is observable through the concurrent dictionary.  And just saying, "no" given the question asked, without clarifying it to mean that you're changing an object the dictionary references, rather than the dictionary itself, is still highly misleading in context.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `ConcurrentBag<T>`:

```
var dic = new ConcurrentDictionary<int, ConcurrentBag<string>>();
```

Something like this could work OK:

```
public static class ConcurentDictionaryExt
{
    public static ConcurrentBag<V> AddToInternal<K, V>(this ConcurrentDictionary<K, ConcurrentBag<V>> dic, K key, V value)
        => dic.AddOrUpdate(key,
            k => new ConcurrentBag<V>() { value },
            (k, existingBag) =>
                {
                    existingBag.Add(value);
                    return existingBag;
                }
            );

    public static ConcurrentBag<V> AddRangeToInternal<K, V>(this ConcurrentDictionary<K, ConcurrentBag<V>> dic, K key, IEnumerable<V> values)
        => dic.AddOrUpdate(key,
            k => new ConcurrentBag<V>(values),
            (k, existingBag) =>
                {
                    foreach (var v in values)
                        existingBag.Add(v);
                    return existingBag;
                }
            );
}
```

I didn't test it yet :)