# list array not changing in model list

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-mvc

Everything is ok but after auth process the _humans list not changing. The last one must add token into list array.

my list array

```
public List<Human> _humans = new List<Human>
{
  new Human ( 1,"test","false","asd" )
};
```

--
non working method:

```
[HttpGet]
public async Task<IActionResult> register( Human employee)
{
  ....
  await HttpContext.SignInAsync(principles);

  humans.Add(new Human(22,"ASDDD","AAS",employee.token));

  return RedirectToAction("Index","Home");
}
```

Comment: Are you using EF, or is `_human` just a local `List`?

Comment: a local list in homecontroller file when i visit index() it adds value to array, but with register () it doesnt add into list

Comment: its basic public list component no EF

Comment: Where do you check if the list has changed?

Comment: in another method.in getvalues() method  i try to get values with jsonresult, but list stays unaffected

Comment: [Authorize]
        [AutoValidateAntiforgeryToken]
        [HttpGet]
        public ObjectResult Index()
        {

            return new ObjectResult(_humans);
        }

Comment: Does the 'register' method throw any error?

Comment: no errrors on webpage it normally returns json but  which is un affected list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As stated in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1763908/1018842) answer a new controller instance will be constructed for each request. So for each request a new list will be created and everything added to it will be lost at the end of the request.

To persist your data you should serialize it to a database or file. You could also make the list `static` but then the data will still be lost when the application restarts.

Comment: where can i put the static list ?

Comment: By changing `public List<Human> _humans = ...` to `public static List<Human> _humans = ...`.

Comment: @barron He is right! You can put the keyword static after the public modifier.

Comment: This will most likely solve your issue. However, it may also create other problems. Static lists are [not threadsafe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8197202/4949005).

Comment: That's true, I'd recommend looking into something like entity framework.